# C# - stream reader issue

Tags: c#, networking, stream

so basically i'm developing a networking program in c# and I'm trying to send a string from the server to the client using stream reader but I'm having a very strange issue. When I use this code...

[Server Side]

```
foreach (DataRow row in StocksTable.Rows)
            {
                stocks += row["description"] + "," + row["buy"] + "," + row["sell"] + ",";
            }
```

[Client]

```
textBox3.Text = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

... it works but it only returns the first row. When I change the "\n" with ";" for example so that everything is on one row, the client crashes.

I tried using an iterator to print all the rows but it doesn't work as well.

I know it sounds funny and probably there's some simple explanation but I've been stuck on this for a while and i'm getting confused.

EDIT:

I tried iterating and this thing works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                textBox3.Text += streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
```

(5 is the number of rows in the string)

but this doesn't:

```
while (true)
            {
                string s = streamReader.ReadLine();
                if (s != null)
                {
                    textBox3.Text += s;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Which classes are you using?

Comment: You're using readline - the \n terminates the line.  If you loop through all lines you may see what you're after.  My guess on the crash would be that the size of the string's too large for the textbox?

Comment: _the client crashes_ -- what are the exception details?

Comment: _I tried using an iterator to print all the rows but it doesn't work as well_ -- how does it not work?  What does this code look like?

Comment: By it doesn't work I mean that the client just freezes and it says not responding after a while. The client is a GUI, and the server is just console so I can't really see what the problem with the client is exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that `stocks` is a string.  A string can contain many lines (lines defined as string delimited by a CR, LF, or CRLF).  In this case it appears you are creating multiple lines in the string by using `\n`.  There for:

```
textBox3.Text = streamReader.ReadLine();
```

Will read the first *Line* in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) in order to read all the lines. `ReadNextLine` will only read a line and stop at a `\n` character.

If you iterate, you should check if more content is still available.